# How can i search in cloudSearch using paths

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudsearch

I have the following directory structure in S3:

```
users(folder)/userCode(folder)/file.json
```

How can I search this specific directory using URI in cloudSearch, and how search a data inside the files in this directory? For example:

```
/search?prefix=users/userCode&q=userName:XXX
```

Comment: Can you share an example of the data structure of one of your documents, as returned by CloudSearch (e.g. `fields: {field1:'...', field2: '...', field3: '...'}`)?  Because depending on how your files are indexed, you may or may not be able to search by the file path as it exists in S3.